# How to deserialize a string into a dict with json loads with unknown function?

Tags: python, json

When I have a string like this

```
test = '{"key1":"value1", "key2": UnknownFunction("value2")}'
```

I cannot use `json.loads` to deserialize its content as the serialized data object contains an unknown function. Is there a simple way to map such a function (or any unknown function) to e.g. `str`, so that I can deserialize the data object to get a dict like

```
{"key1":"value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

?

The following code is working but maybe there is some better way?

```
for removable in ["UnknownFunction"]:
    test= test.replace(removable + "(", "")
test = test.replace(")", "")
data = json.loads(test)
```

Comment: You cannot, because at this point you're no longer parsing JSON but running code, pretty much. There is no such thing as a "function" in JSON.

Comment: So I have to find the location of the string `UnknownFunction`, remove it, and the following two brackets myself before I deserialize the string?

Comment: That would be most sensible thing, I guess. Depends on why are you getting this instead of actual JSON string.

Comment: I get an object like this and want to parse it into a dict. I cannot change the creation of the string. I have to work with what I have

Comment: You might try to write a custom decoder that behaves like a normal one as long as the objects are valid JSON and when it encounters incorrect value like `UnknownFunction("value2")` it tries to parse it according to your needs.

Comment: @matszwecja And how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) using your own [`NodeTransformer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer) to handle function calls:

```
import ast


class Transformer(ast.NodeTransformer):

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        super().generic_visit(node)
        if isinstance(node, ast.Call):
            _args = node.args
            return _args if len(_args) > 0 else ast.Constant(value='null')
        return node


def transform_eval(py_str):
    return ast.literal_eval(Transformer().visit(ast.parse(py_str,
                                                          mode='eval')).body)


testStr = """        {
        "key1": "value1", 
        "key2": UnknownFunction("value1"),
        "key3": foo(),
        }"""

print(transform_eval(testStr.strip()))
```

Out:

```
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value1', 'key3': 'null'}
```

**Note**:
I haven't checked if all possible function argument combinations work: `UnknownFunction("value1", foo="bar")` or `UnknownFunction(*args, foo="bar")`